# How to receive Non-primitive data in WebMethod?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, web-services, webmethod

I am trying to pass an array of bytes to my WebMethod through JavaScript.
The problem is that my WebMethod returns with the message "The test form is only available for primitive methods as parameters."

When I change data type to string or any other kind of primitive variables the WebMethod accepts it goes on.

I'm transforming an object into a byte[], named msgpackEnvio using MessagePack(The transformation itself occurs well), and then sending to WebService.

Here's my request to WebService using jquery

```
$.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function (request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    },
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: url,
                    data: msgpackEnvio,
                    type: "POST",
                    error: function (data) {
                        $('#upload-load').hide();
                        $('.bt-enviar-excel').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        var msg = document.getElementsByClassName('msg')[0];
                        msg.style.color = 'red';
                        msg.innerHTML = 'Erro interno servidor!';
                    },
                    success: //some code
```

In fact, the code above doesn't matters at all, my problem is in the webService, and how to make it receive an array or perhaps an object.

And here's my WebMethod that should be able to receive a byte[]

```
 [WebMethod]
public string TestMessagePack(byte[] name)
{        
    //my code

    return "Finish";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoding and decoding to send byte arrays as strings. Anything more than that and you might want to use post requests and JSON serialization/deserialization instead. There's not going to be a generic one size fits all conversion between complex C# objects and javascript objects which is why only primitive parameters are allowed, so for nonprimitive things you'll need a translation layer. That's normally going to mean some form of string serialization and deserialization.

Comment: I tryed it, but the problem that I want to solve is exactly this one. When I read some objects, my json becames so big that the connection to WebService takes to long and even some times there is a time connection error.
I really need to change the WebService method to receive non-primitive

Comment: How would the javascript know to build a non-primitive object that C# could understand? Complex objects are going to be dependent on their language and environment in terms of what they actually look like under the hood, so to bridge that gap serialization comes into play. Complex objects will in one way or another need to be serialized into a string (a primitive type that both layers know how to deal with) to send and deserialized from a string back into a complex object to receive. JSON/XML/etc and base64 are your friends here.

Comment: Some simpler types will be able to be serialized and deserialized automatically although that's not something I'd rely on and if they become more complex you'll need to move to something like json or xml anyway. Where is this error message coming from? It's not in the referenced code and is not a standard error message.